# CSS Float makes content go down for smaller screens

Tags: css

While using media queries for screen resolutions of tablet and mobile phones, the "sideNav" which contains all the links and the social media buttons on the right hand side does remain floated but the "maincontent" section containing all the content goes down and does not stay up floating the "sideNav". I am not able to understand why? The "sideNav" normally floats on the right of the "maincontent" but it does not on resizing.

The code for a small size desktop monitor :

```
@media (max-width:1100px) and (min-width:767px){
body{
width:90%;
margin:auto;
}
#body, #wrap{
width:100%;
margin:auto;
}
#maincontent{
font-size:100%;
width:auto;
margin:auto;
border:1px solid black;
}
#header{
font-size:100%;
display:inline-block;
}
#google_translate_element{
display:inline-block;
}
#search{
}
#breadCrumb{
height:1em;
padding-top:1%;
font-size:95%;
}
#navbox{
height:2em;
margin-bottom:1%;
margin-top:2%;
width:100%;
}
#navbox li{
margin:none;
font-size:95%;
}
#sideNav{
width:30%;
padding:0;
border:1px solid black;

}
}
```

The page with the problem : http://analyzedstock.com/testing/basics-of-stock-market.html

CSS : http://analyzedstock.com/testing/main.css

Please resize the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem caused by rule: `#header { width: 100%; }`

Please try to remove or adjust it to make site work properly in smaller screens.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. That was the reason why it was not working.

Comment: Can I ask for another favor? As I resize the browser, the search bar on the top slowly shifts down and alters the look of the navbar as a new object is entering the territory of it. How can I make the search bar stay on the same place as I resize?

Comment: You have to adjust this rule: `@media (max-width: 768px) { #search { width: 100%; } }`

Comment: I feel you misunderstood what I am trying to convey here. That problem is not present for mobile devices but only for tablets and small desktops. Refer to changes before the screen adjusts for mobile devices and you will see that the search bar slowly occupies the space below and hurts the look of the navbar.

Comment: `<div id="logo">` and `<div id="search">` have a width rule of 40% so once they resize take 40% of the available space. If you want to make them with static size you have to specify a width in pixels.